# Android navigation with google.navigation like Uber

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I'm starting an Intent.ACTION_VIEW to navigation like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+lat+","+lng+"&mode=d");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

this works great and i also created a button with

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

that is always available on screen and when i click it, it resume my app.

Now what i need is...  when i'm in navigation intent if i click the button that resumes my app i also want to close the current navigation app just like Uber.
In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZF7yQK4uMs is an exemple of how i want it to be. At minute: 3:12 he starts the navigation and after that it will show a button in the middle-left of the screen that returns him to uber app, when the navigation is over at 3:30 he clicks that button and returns him to uber app. At this point my app is doing just like that but in the video when he returns to uber app the navigation app is closed and this is what i need.